# How to upgrade Gatsby Starter blog without losing content?

Tags: gatsby

I setup a gatsby blog few months ago using the `gatsby-starter-blog` and it seems many changes have been made by the contributors of the starter, and I would like to update/upgrade the starter.

I'm now wondering how I can efficiently upgrade it (and its dependencies) without losing my content. I see two options:

1. Copy the `content/` folder to a new Gatsby starter project, but I will lose my commit history (I'm using branches for WIP posts), and I have to setup again all the plugins I installed
2. Manually change the starter core code, which I can do by creating a new blog locally, and copy/paste all the differences I see between the new version and the one I have

Both approaches are not easy, so I'm wondering if there is something simpler I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a typical workflow for starters, so there isn't a great automated approach. This is one of the pain points that Gatsby Themes address, but it sounds like you were using this starter before themes launched.

If you have a separate repo for the up-to-date starter cloned you can do a simple diff between the two folders to get a sense of what's new:

```
diff -x .git -r your-blog newer-blog-starter
```

From there you can review the changes and decide what to copy over manually.

There are other approaches that leverage git, but I don't think the outcome will be desirable since the changes aren't likely to apply cleanly.

Comment: Thanks @coreyward, I didn't know about Themes, which indeed solves the problem. I'll migrate my blog to use themes which solves definitely the upgrade issue. Here is a step-by-step guide https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/themes/converting-a-starter/